# Prove $ \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n} ( - 1)^{\lfloor k\alpha \rfloor}$ is unbounded where $\alpha$ is irrational.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Obviously, value of $ ( - 1)^{\lfloor k\alpha \rfloor}$ depends on $ \{k\alpha\}$. This sequence is uniformly distrubuted $ \mod 1$. We have
$ \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n} ( - 1)^{\lfloor k\alpha \rfloor} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n} f\left(k\frac {\alpha}{2} \right)$, where $ f$ is defined by
$ f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\leqslant x < \frac {1}{2} \\
-1 & \frac {1}{2}\leqslant x < 1 \end{array} \right.$

How to go on with this?

Comment: Your $f$ is rapidly inadequate.  $k \alpha/2$ is larger than $1$ once $k > 2/\alpha$.

Comment: I've seen this question asked, then deleted here a few days ago. Where did you find this problem? I'm concerned that it's an open contest problem.

Comment: Something very similar appeared in the Olympiades de Première 2020 (first Paris academic exercise, not online yet though).
Let $ f_\alpha(M) = \int_0^M(-1)^{\lfloor\alpha x\rfloor}\mathrm dx $. When is $ f_\alpha $ bounded if $ \alpha $ is rational, if $ \alpha $ is irrational?

Answer (score 1):

To see more about this problem, you can read the paper **On a conjecture of Erdős and Szüsz related to uniform distribution mod 1**, which proves that

> For any irrational number $\alpha$, $\sum_{k=1}^n\left(-1\right)^{\lfloor k\alpha \rfloor}$
>   is unbounded.

Comment: Could you summarize? Is the unboundedness only a conjecture as the title suggests, or do the (not named by you) authors of said paper claim the unboundednes, or perhaps even prove it?